# Can I describe state as action without context?

Tags: verbs

For example, without context, can I describe the meaning of 'something is in the air' as 'something is going up in the air'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These sentences are not quite interchangeable:

'something is going up in the air' -  Something is travelling upwards and will be or already is in the air. Note: **into** the air sounds a bit more natural here.

'Something is in the air' - Something is currently in the air and may be still or may be moving in any direction

So there is a difference between the description as a state and as an action.

Comment: _Something is in the air_ (or _There's something in the air_) could also refer to a smell or vapour of some kind which is noticeable in the atmosphere.